# XCode doesn't recognise Core ML model files

Tags: swift, machine-learning, swift3, coreml

I download Core ML model files from Apple's web page but my mac and XCode don't recognise them. Here is what I see when I add them to my project navigator:

[image: this is what I see when I tap on the file in XCode]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A few possibilities: (1) CoreML is iOS 11 so you need to be working in Xcode 9. (2) Can you provide both the model file name and where you downloaded it from? (3) The current version of Xcode - Beta 2 - is extremely buggy on adding files. The one way Apple suggests adding *.mlmodel* files is by dragging it into your project. I just downloaded *SqueezeNet.mlmodel* from their site and it worked perfectly.

Comment: My Xcode version is 8.3.3. Maybe that is the reason of the problem. Thank you for your help.)
P.s. I download models from apple's web page.

Comment: That is *definately* the issue. (Well, unless you can specify iOS 11 in Xcode 8!) Just remember, Xcode 9 Beta 2 is still a bit buggy. Two more things.... (1) It can co-exist with Xcode 8 but **will** install as the default version of Xcode (meaning you need to command-click your Xcode 8 app that way. (2) Beta 2 is buggy but they are pretty good with releases every few weeks. Also, it uses Swift 4 by default, and (I believe) Swift 3.2 otherwise. Welcome to the Apple post-WWDC summer of upgrading! And good luck and good coding.

Comment: A separate comment - the **best** resource I've found for ML - both CoreML and otherwise - is http://machinethink.net/blog/. A very good blog with great details about ML in particular. His last article (like most) has a link to a GitHub project (Xcode 9 Beta 2) with a really good explanation on importing a trained model into CoreML. He has a few other repositories that may help you, including code to convert something to a `CVPixelBuffer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem and noticed that **XCode 9 Beta 4** has a bug in which every time you drag a **mlmodel** to your project it does not get added to the target even though you selected your target to add.

The solution is to click the file and tick the "Add to target" box located in the utilities tab. (XCode's right panel)

Comment: It's been a few months, and IIRC, this kind of behavior happened on other things too - I think dragging a simple image into your project (for instance a small image) or even a class from another project and then deleting it from the source folder had the same behavior. When was it *finally*(!) corrected?